# how to extract string from ansible regsiter variable in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have written the following ansible playbook to find the disk failure on the raid

```
- name: checking raid status
  shell: "cat /proc/mdstat | grep nvme"
  register: "array_check"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ array_check.stdout_lines }}"
```

Following is the output I got

```
"msg": [
    "md0 : active raid1 nvme0n1p1[0] nvme1n1p1[1]", 
    "md2 : active raid1 nvme1n1p3[1](F) nvme0n1p3[0]", 
    "md1 : active raid1 nvme1n1p2[1] nvme0n1p2[0]"
]
```

I want to extract the disk name which is failed from the register variable `array_check`.

How do I do this in the ansible? Can I use `set_fact` module in ansible? Can I use grep, awk, sed command on the register variable `array_check`

---

This is the playbook I am using to check the health status of a drive using smartctl

```
- name: checking the smartctl logs
shell: "smartctl -H /dev/{{ item }}"
with_items:
        - nvme0
        - nvme1
```

And I am facing the following error

```
(item=nvme0) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "smartctl -H /dev/nvme0", "delta": "0:00:00.090760", "end": "2019-09-05 11:21:17.035173", "failed": true, "item": "nvme0", "rc": 127, "start": "2019-09-05 11:21:16.944413", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: smartctl: not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}

(item=nvme1) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "smartctl -H /dev/nvme1", "delta": "0:00:00.086596", "end": "2019-09-05 11:21:17.654036", "failed": true, "item": "nvme1", "rc": 127, "start": "2019-09-05 11:21:17.567440", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: smartctl: not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

The desired output should be something like this,

```
=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

Comment: You can use ansible filters to extract a specific substring from variables. Try to write the task for that, and If you are stuck in that, then please share your progress and we can help you from there.

Comment: thank you.. i will try.. How can we check the health of a disk using ansible. I tried to use the smartctl command in the playbook to check the health of the disk,  but it gives the error as `"stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: smartctl: not found"`

Comment: Edit the question and Add the task along with the output so that we can have a look.

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: It seems that the `smartctl` is not present on the specified host

Comment: Ansible host and the remote host both have smartctl installed

Comment: Okay, but the error clearly states that it was unable to find `smartctl`. It may be possible that your `PATH` is not configured properly due to which it is not able to find that particular binary. You can do one thing, you can provide the absolute path to the binary like `/usr/bin/smartctl`

Comment: I tried to use the complete path for smartctl /usr/sbin/smartctl, playbook gave me the error `"Smartctl open device: /dev/nvme0 failed: Permission denied"`. So I added `sudo /usr/sbin/smartctl /dev/nvme0`. Now, the playbook hangs at the step `TASK [checking the smartctl logs]`... I also used `remote_user: root` still no use

Comment: If you have specified `remote_user:root` the ansible is trying to ssh to that machine using that user and you can use `become:true` instead.

Comment: Is you issue fixed?

Comment: issue is still not fixed and I have been trying for many days. I created a ansible user which has sudo permission and ran the ansible playbook with `remote_user: ansible` and `become: true`, still the ansible playbook fails. if I use `remote_user: root` and `become: true` and run the playbook, it gives error `UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\n
", "unreachable": true}`. I tired with complete path `/usr/sbin/smartctl' and 'sudo smartctl` nothing is working.

Comment: You can do the following things, `1st` - Try to SSH to that machine using the user you have created and also try an adhoc command to ping to the SSH machine. `2nd` - Use command module of ansible instead of shell module. `3rd` - When you use `ansible` user does it connects or fails to connect. If it connects successfully, it means you can use that user but your command fails, as it is clear that you are facing connectivity issues with `root` user.

Comment: And also try to be a bit more active, to get instant response and help.

Comment: there is no root password set for the server. i ma logging in using ssh key. i am able to login to the server using my username and then run `sudo su` in order to become root user and then do `su - ansible`to login as the ansible user.. I tried with `command` module, but the playbook hangs at the `command` module step

Comment: Do one thing, use `become:true` and `become_user:ansible` for your task. It will login using the default user which is being used and will run the command with `ansible` user.

Comment: I used as you said but it gives the error `"sudo: a password is required` and we do not have a password for ansible user

Comment: this is the playbook i wrote                                                                                         `---
- hosts: raid_host
  remote_user: ansible
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: checking raid status
    shell: "cat /proc/mdstat | grep 'F' | cut -d' ' -f6 | cut -d'[' -f1"
    register: "array_check"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ array_check.stdout_lines }}"

  - name: checking the samrtctl logs for the drive
    shell: "sudo /usr/sbin/smartctl -H /dev/nvme0"
    register: "smartctl_status"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199900/discussion-between-shubham-vaishnav-and-user11549576).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the complete playbook including the logic to execute multiple commands in a single task using `with_items`,

```
--- 
 - hosts: raid_host
   remote_user: ansible
   become: yes
   become_method: sudo 
   tasks: 
     - name: checking raid status 
       shell: "cat /proc/mdstat | grep 'F' | cut -d' ' -f6 | cut -d'[' -f1" 
       register: "array_check"

     - debug:
        msg: "{{ array_check.stdout_lines }}"

     - name: checking the samrtctl logs for the drive 
       shell: "/usr/sbin/smartctl -H /dev/{{ item }} | tail -2|awk -F' ' '{print $6}'"
       with_items:
         - "nvme0"
         - "nvme1"
       register: "smartctl_status"
```

Comment: BTW the actual question in the thread has not been answered `I want to extract the disk name which is failed from the register variable array_check`

Comment: Okay. Will add that part too.